# Is there performance difference between concat vs || in oracle

Tags: oracle, concatenation

I want to concat multiple(3) columns in oracle sql query. Currently I am using function `concat`. 
Someone suggested to use `||` in place of `concat` as it gives performance benefit.

Is it true? If yes why?

I see only benefit of || is that written query more readable.

Answer (score 11):

I set up a simple PL/SQL script(below) to try both concatenation options within a loop 100 million times each. The result for `||` was 142.93 seconds and `CONCAT` was 144.11 seconds. Either way, you're talking about roughly 1.4 microseconds per operation. My conclusion is that there doesn't appear to be any appreciable performance difference.

In addition to being more readable, `||` is the ANSI standard for the concatenation operator.

---

```
DECLARE
   i NUMBER;
   j NUMBER := 100000000;
   v VARCHAR2 (1000);
   v_start TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. j LOOP
      v := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE () || DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE ();
   END LOOP;    
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('1: ' || (SYSTIMESTAMP - v_start));
END;

DECLARE
   i NUMBER;
   j NUMBER := 100000000;
   v VARCHAR2 (1000);
   v_start TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. j LOOP
      v := CONCAT (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (), DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE ());
   END LOOP;    
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('2: ' || (SYSTIMESTAMP - v_start));
END;
```

---

As a footnote, [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm#i997789) says this about purpose of the `CONCAT` function:

> When moving SQL script files between systems having different
>   character sets, such as between ASCII and EBCDIC, vertical bars might
>   not be translated into the vertical bar required by the target Oracle
>   Database environment. Oracle provides the CONCAT character function as
>   an alternative to the vertical bar operator for cases when it is
>   difficult or impossible to control translation performed by operating
>   system or network utilities. Use this function in applications that
>   will be moved between environments with differing character sets.

Comment: Some of my collegues indicate that their queries using pipes sometimes fail while the CONCAT function doesn't. I don't think in our situation it is a problem with different character sets, but the network / operating system problem is interesting. I'm converting C7 .imr files to C10 (web based) so I'm switching to ||.

Answer (score 4):

Both are just the same, `CONCAT()` is for supporting different Characters sets for SQL Script handling, where `'||'` might be interpreted wrongly.

From [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm#i997789)

> On most platforms, the concatenation operator is two solid vertical
>   bars, as shown in Table 4-3. However, some IBM platforms use broken
>   vertical bars for this operator. When moving SQL script files between
>   systems having different character sets, such as between ASCII and
>   EBCDIC, vertical bars might not be translated into the vertical bar
>   required by the target Oracle Database environment. Oracle provides
>   the CONCAT character function as an alternative to the vertical bar
>   operator for cases when it is difficult or impossible to control
>   translation performed by operating system or network utilities. Use
>   this function in applications that will be moved between environments
>   with differing character sets.