# Oracle/SQL to SQL Server translation

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I work in **MS SQL Server** and I've never used **PLSQL**, but I recently received a line of code from a colleague (see below):

```
substr(Field1, 1, 8)||'*'||SUBSTR(Field1, 10, 1)
```

I can take care of the `substr` -> `substring` bit easily enough, but I'm lost as to what `||'*'||` means/does; is it concatenation, or something else I've not thought of yet?

Comment: Depending on context, a gotcha is that Oracle treats zero length VARCHARs and NULL as synonymous, sometimes acting nullish, sometimes not. In Oracle `null||'*'` yields `'*'` whereas on SQL Server `null+'*'` will yield `null`. Depending on the chances of the substrings returning null, you might wrap in `coalesce(substring(...), '')` to get similar behavior on SQL Server.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator in Oracle's (and as @a_horse_with_no_name commented - standard ANSI) SQL is indeed the concatination operator between strings. In MS SQL Server's SQL, you would just use `+`. So the translation would be:

```
SUBSTRING(Field1, 1, 8) + '*' + SUBSTRING(Field1, 10, 1)
```

Comment: @eddymc2: it's actually not "Oracle's" concatenation operator. `||` is the operator that is defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: I was under the impression that `+` was the standard SQL way of concatinating string and that `||` was Oracle's proprietary syntax. Learned something new today. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: @Mureinik: nope, pretty much every DBMS uses the standard `||` except for Microsoft and MySQL - even though that standard was defined long before those DBMS existed.

Answer (score 1):

Like @MarcB said it's concatenation, `|| {string here} ||` is equivalent to `+` or `concat()` in SQL Server:

```
substring(Field1, 1, 8)+ '*' + substring(Field1, 10, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, FutbolFan! Good luck this season!

Answer (score 0):

> The result of concatenating two character strings is another character
>   string. If both character strings are of datatype CHAR, the result has
>   datatype CHAR and is limited to 2000 characters. If either string is
>   of datatype VARCHAR2, the result has datatype VARCHAR2 and is limited
>   to 4000 characters. If either argument is a CLOB, the result is a
>   temporary CLOB. Trailing blanks in character strings are preserved by
>   concatenation, regardless of the datatypes of the string or CLOB.
>
> On most platforms, the concatenation operator is two solid vertical
>   bars, as shown in Table 4-3. However, some IBM platforms use broken
>   vertical bars for this operator. When moving SQL script files between
>   systems having different character sets, such as between ASCII and
>   EBCDIC, vertical bars might not be translated into the vertical bar
>   required by the target Oracle Database environment. Oracle provides
>   the CONCAT character function as an alternative to the vertical bar
>   operator for cases when it is difficult or impossible to control
>   translation performed by operating system or network utilities. Use
>   this function in applications that will be moved between environments
>   with differing character sets.
>
> Although Oracle treats zero-length character strings as nulls,
>   concatenating a zero-length character string with another operand
>   always results in the other operand, so null can result only from the
>   concatenation of two null strings. However, this may not continue to
>   be true in future versions of Oracle Database. To concatenate an
>   expression that might be null, use the NVL function to explicitly
>   convert the expression to a zero-length string.

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm#i997789)

To have a more clear source code you could consider to use [CONCAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm)

This is a post [about perfomance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26103225/2912399)